# How to connect my XMPP server (ejabberd) with Firebase for Chat APP Android

Tags: android, firebase, xmpp

Im doing an client app with xmpp server to send / receive message between clients...
**I use smack library** on Android to connect **with XMPP server**.
But when i close my app dont receive the messages and i want to connect my xmpp server with firebase for when i re open my app i can receive the message...
Im reading about *Firebase but im so confused*, i can receive notifications from firebase console, but i want something that when i receive a message (not necesary if my app is closed okay) i can see the message... 
**I dont know how to connect xmpp with firebase** to do that :(